# How to make a secure connection to ec2 instance on aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have managed to connect my ec2 instance to my domain with route 53. However im now having issues making the connection secure. I have tried to follow step by step instructions found on stack exchange however am still having issues and wonder if anyone can help me.

I created a secure certificate with the amazon certificate manager and connected this to a load manager which is linked to my ec2 instance. [image]

I then used the DNS name on the load balancer and added this to my route 53 configuration.[image] Something I cant quite understand is when I test the record set on route 53 I get the IP 3.129.2.237 returned (which still loads the ec2 instance), not the ip4v value found on the ec2 instance 18.217.221.40.

Ive then taken the name server values and put them into my dynadot (host) name server settings.

I have restarted my gunicorn server that im using on the ec2 instance. It is running on port 9090, in the Nginx settings (/etc/nginx/sites-available/default) I set proxy_pass to http://0.0.0.0:9090.

The site runs when doing a http:// request (http://www.advancedmatchedbetting.com)but not when a https request occurs [enter link description here](https://www.advancedmatchedbetting.com).

If anyone has any idea where im going wrong it would be most apreciated. If it's of any help, it is a Django app running react as a frontend.

Edit: launch wizard protocol:

[image]

Dynadot settings:
[image]

Amazon Certificate Manager:
[image]

New Dynadot Settings:
[image]

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the response. Yes I think so. Because of the proxy_pass I figured that would be ok (www.advancedmatchedbetting.com:80 works for me), but im not sure if there's something I missing. Not 100% sure what you mean by target groups, ive added pictures of the launch wizard is this is it??

Comment: Its ok. I deleted earlier message. I see now you are using classic LB. HTTPs works. I verified it using `curl -k https://amb-load-balancer-1591853416.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com`. Which makes me believe that the issue has something to do with the ssl. What domain was it register for?

Comment: @Marcin Cheers. It is registered for advancedmatchedbetting.com using dynadot to register it. I've copied and pasted a photo from dynadot and amazon certificate registration. It may be a side note but when I change SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT from false to true in my Django settings it causes the app to not load, I instead just get a blank screen, not sure if that helps you find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Oh I see. You specified IP address of the instance in your A record. You have to create CNAME record to the ALB url.

Comment: Can you change the records and check if this resolves the issue?

Comment: @Marcin Is it on dynadot that I change it? Do I leave the A record or delete it?

Comment: Can you just provide the url for the CLB instead of IP. I'm familiar with how dynadot works. Maybe you can leave A record and just use CLB's url instead of IP of the instance.

Comment: @Marcin I've put a photo in the domain of what I have updated it to  if that is right?

Comment: You just recently changed the Route 53 entry from your EC2 instance to your load balancer, but you're still seeing the IP of your EC2? Then you're simply dealing with DNS caching…?

Comment: @deceze yep, good point, now that ive changed the DNS settings I'll leave it a while and hope that it reroutes.

Comment: Ok. Let me know how it will go.

Comment: @Marcin all up now. Thanks so so so much for all your help today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was that the **incorrect records** set for the domain. They were set to the IP of the instance, rather then the url of the CLB.

The **solution** was to change the records to the correct values.